# How to work a jQuery lightbox gallery in ReactJS Component?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I Have this jQuery lightbox plugin: http://simplelightbox.com/

I can´t implement its on react app. Everything is working good in a simple html app, but in React it isn't working. can everybody help me to solve it? Thank you.

here in the **index.html** page

```
<title>My website</title> 
  <link href="simplelightbox-master/dist/simplelightbox.min.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>        

  <div id="root"></div>   

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="simplelightbox-master/dist/simple-lightbox.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function(){    
      var $gallery = $('.gallery a').simpleLightbox();     

   });

  </script>    

</body>
```

Here is my React component who i want to show the lightbox gallery

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'   

class Interiores extends Component {    


  render() {    
    return (
      <div>    
        <div className="gallery">
          <a href="../../simplelightbox-master/demo/images/image1.jpg" className="big"><img src="../../simplelightbox-master/demo/images/thumbs/thumb1.jpg" alt="" title="Beautiful Image" /></a>
      </div>            

     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="../../simplelightbox-master/dist/simple-lightbox.min.js"></script>               

      </div>
    )
  }      
}

export default Interiores;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is based on 2 simple steps:
All of these changes are in the component that is using the gallery.

**First**: You just put this commentary line below for the lint accept the '$' sinal and it won't generate an error message.

```
/* global $ */
import React, { Component } from 'react'
    ...rest of the code here
```

**Second:** You need to put the main jquery's plugin function inside the React function 'conponentDidMount()'

```
componentDidMount() {    
  $(function () {
    var $gallery = $('.gallery a').simpleLightbox();      
  });    
}
```

I tested these changes and it is working successfully.

Answer (score 2):

You should use react-simplelightbox https://github.com/ts-de/react-simple-lightbox

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how to implement a thumbnail?

Comment: uhum!This document is poor.I think you should make your component for save time :D

Comment: Sadly!That lib not provides props or event for custom.You have to read code in src/SimpleLightbox.js and write event click in child component for switch thumbnail  and original image.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're using a build tool, Webpack or similar? The reason it's not working is most likely because the `script` tags your component renders don't actually reference anything once the project is bundled, i.e. the scripts aren't included because they're not imported and therefore the build tool doesn't pick them up as a dependency and include them.

If you really want/need to use a jQuery plugin in this way, you should import the third-party script via an import/require and use it as the `script`'s source so your build-tool imports it properly:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'   
import * as Lightbox from '../../simplelightbox-master/dist/simple-lightbox.min.js'

class Interiores extends Component {    
  render() {    
    return (
      <div>    
        <div className="gallery">
          <a href="../../simplelightbox-master/demo/images/image1.jpg" className="big"><img src="../../simplelightbox-master/demo/images/thumbs/thumb1.jpg" alt="" title="Beautiful Image" /></a>
      </div>            

     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src={Lightbox}></script>               
      </div>
    )
  }      
}

export default Interiores;
```

Using jQuery in this way however, with React goes against the very nature of React and its components. The recommended solution is to use a third-party component like the one recommended by Haidangdevhaui. Or, because a lightbox is actually quite simple, just create your own lightbox component. [React state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) will come in handy.